# nginx auth_request is always true and never seen

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx with Flask through uwsgi with the auth_request directive as following:

```
    location /protected/ {
            auth_request /auth;
            auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/protected/;
    }

    location = /auth/ {
            #internal;
            try_files $uri @uwsgi_socket;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri @uwsgi_socket;
    }
```

Without the auth_request parameter, accessing /protected works just fine.

When accessing the path /auth or /anyfile, I get the expected answers. But when I try to access /protected, I have the following nginx error:

```
sept. 25 15:12:01  nginx[12548]:  nginx: 2018/09/25 15:12:01 [error] 12548#12548: *3 auth request unexpected status: 301, client: 172.18.8.143, server: _, request: "GET /protected/ HTTP/1.1", host: "myhost.com"
```

It seems /auth is never requested upon accessing /protected, since uwsgi does not display any log but:

```
[pid: 12155|app: 0|req: 55/55] 192.18.8.146 () {56 vars in 1256 bytes} [Tue Sep 25 15:27:06 2018] GET /protected/ => generated 297 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 301) 3 headers in 152 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Which should not happen since /protected is supposed to be redirected to :8080

Comment: It doesn't work with `return 200 ...`. The rewrite module (which implements `return`) is executed early in the process of a request, I would guess that `return` takes precedence over `auth_request`. Do you need a `return 200 ...` or was that just for test purposes?

Comment: It was just for test purposes. I am editing the question to show my problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem was due to "/" :

```
    location = /auth {
            try_files $uri @uwsgi
    }
```

works perfectly